# Contributions - Receipt (on-line) Transaction # in Message Template missing

Tags: contributions, message-templates

Since some update in the 4.x line we do not get the Transaction # from contributions in the message template anymore. This happens although the ID gets recorded in the DB correctly.

This is the part that never gets executed because $trxn_id is empty ($is_monetary = 1).

```
{if $is_monetary and $trxn_id}
  <tr>
    <td {$labelStyle}>
      {ts}Transaction #{/ts}
    </td>
    <td {$valueStyle}>
      {$trxn_id}
    </td>
  </tr>
{/if}
```

We use the PayflowPRO processor (modified).

Any ideas?

Comment: not clear what version you mean? 4.4.x? 4.7.x? something else?

Comment: i am on the latest version, 4.7.4

Comment: and you are using the Default Template?

Comment: No, I am using my own. But at the point as quoted above there is no difference. I have upgraded to v.4.7.6 already and the issue still remains.

Also: I have tried the default Payflow Pro processor, just to exclude the possibility that it has something to do with our mods. But that did not do anything either.